# Jq: why does del() leave null in place?

Tags: jq

I have to recursively remove objects that contain a given key value.

The Json is:

```
{
    "health": "yellow",
    "status": "open",
    "index": ".monitoring-es-2-2017.03.03",
    "uuid": "Py3FY-UwSjmda3jbYeIdMg",
    "pri": "1",
    "rep": "1",
    "docs.count": "23494",
    "docs.deleted": "78",
    "store.size": "12mb",
    "pri.store.size": "12mb"
  },
  {
    "health": "yellow",
    "status": "open",
    "index": "robot-log-01.02.2017",
    "uuid": "lFndm8gDS2OAGXZhP5KSkw",
    "pri": "5",
    "rep": "1",
    "docs.count": "127887",
    "docs.deleted": "0",
    "store.size": "35.1mb",
    "pri.store.size": "35.1mb"
  }
```

Config is:

```
walk( if ((type == "object" and has("index")) and (."index" | test("monitoring*"))) then del(.) else . end )
```

Output is:

```
null,
      {
        "health": "yellow",
        "status": "open",
        "index": "robot-log-01.02.2017",
        "uuid": "lFndm8gDS2OAGXZhP5KSkw",
        "pri": "5",
        "rep": "1",
        "docs.count": "127887",
        "docs.deleted": "0",
        "store.size": "35.1mb",
        "pri.store.size": "35.1mb"
      }
```

Why does del() leave null in place? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief, use `empty` instead of `del(.)`.  After simplifying:

walk(if type == "object" and has("index") and (.index | test("monitoring")) 
        then empty else . end )